Which approach is grammatically correct ''reaching anyone'' (in the past)
Option1: He wasn't available and I couldn't had reached anyone before that via reception at +49123456. If I did, I wouldn't be calling him.
Option2: He wasn't available and I couldn't have reached anyone before that via reception at +49123456. If I did, I wouldn't be calling him.
Thank you.

"I couldn't have reached anyone" is hypothetical - it means you didn't try but if you did try you would have failed. Is that what you mean.

(1) couldn't had is incorrect.
(2) can't work either, with couldn't have reached.
Couldn't reach would work:
He wasn't available and I couldn't reach anyone before that via reception at +49123456. If I did, I wouldn't be calling him.

Not sure what you mean with "... couldn't have reached anyone means you actually reached someone".

Thanks, @TimR.  I've edited my answer.
